# Считывать "свайпы" пальцем по экрану Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно отслеживать свайп пальцем на "Unity c#". Мне надо чтобы когда игрок делал свайп по экрану, игровая камера двигалась по карте, но не выходила за границы как в Clash Of Clans.

Comment: вы на русской части сайта,переведите свой вопрос на русский язык пожалуйста.

Comment: и, кстати, вы в вопросе указали, что вам надо сделать, но не указали, в чем проблема это сделать, как вы решали сами эту задачу и что у вас не получилось. Пока что в вашем вопросе нет самого вопроса, то есть по сути отвечать не на что

Comment: Посмотрите ассет "Lean Touch". На мой взгляд, вполне неплохо работает.
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/lean-touch-30111

Comment: В гугле есть уроки по камере, поищите. Не ограничивайтесь, ищите на английском, т.к особо понимать не надо. Вот один пример https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfjLQrMGEb4

Comment: Вот обучающий материал по Touch для Unity, https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/s/mobile-touch А насчет камеры просто создаете менеджер камеры и делаете его Singleton.

Comment: Следует закрыть. Автор, потрудитесь не ссылатся на игру в которую, скорее всего, участники не играли. Если уж приводится пример из игры -- то нужно или снять видео или же ссылатся на конкретное видео. Почему учасники должны разбиратся в вопросе сами и гуглить вместо автора вопроса? Им нужнее?